# Do you provide support "to" or "for" a task?

Tags: word-choice, verbs, prepositions

I would like to know which is correct?

1. This software provides comprehensive support *to* user tasks.
2. This software provides comprehensive support *for* user tasks.

Comment: Depends on the context.

Comment: What context do you need?

Comment: *for*..........

Comment: Is this [task](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Task_(computing)) as in thread/process, or task as in something a person has to do?

Comment: The task is in something a person has to do.

Answer (score 1):

> This software provides comprehensive support for user tasks.

In this context, you are explaining the reason why the software provides "comprehensive support". Since "user tasks" is a *noun*, you would use for in this case.  If instead of a noun we had a *verb* like "help users complete their tasks". The sentence would be:

> This software provides comprehensive support to help users complete their tasks.